# I run Bitcoin Core 0.14.1, for Segwit they tell me to "upgrade" to 0.13.1. So confusing

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness

**Short version** of my question: I run Bitcoin Core 0.14.1. Will I be fully compatible with the segwit soft fork after Aug 1 2017 with this version? IOW, I can simply do nothing and be segwit compatible?

**The long version** of this same question:
I'm running Bitcoin Core] version 0.14.1. I upgraded to that several months ago. I have the full blockchain downloaded. I've been running core since 2014 with periodic upgrades.

I now see all the news about a hard fork and Segwit but finding clear information about how it affects me as a Core Node host and having Bitcoin Core wallets has been difficult and confusing.

The Bitcoin Core website tells me I can choose to "not upgrade" for segwit or I can "upgrade" to 0.13.1. They never say anything like "if you have any version above 0.13.1 you already have Segwit so you're good to go." I want to emphasize that I have not found anyone saying that having any version of Bitcoin Core above 0.13.1 means I'm good to go with the new soft fork.

Sorry, I don't feel comfortable making assumptions. Sure, I know it seems obvious that later versions should include what's in earlier versions, but there has been so much talk about this soft fork and so very little information about what people like me need to do who have a Bitcoin Core wallet and am running core so that I can use that wallet.

[This Bitcoin Core page](https://bitcoincore.org/en/2016/10/27/segwit-upgrade-guide/) (Segregated Witness Upgrade Guide) says:

"The easiest way to prevent this problem is to upgrade to Bitcoin Core 0.13.1 ***or another full node release that is compatible with the segwit soft fork***. If you still don’t wish to upgrade, it is possible to use a newer Bitcoin Core release as a filter for older Bitcoin Core releases."

"Full nodes run by a reasonable number of users and business to validate the payments they receive need to be upgraded to Bitcoin Core 0.13.1 or another segwit-compatible implementation in order to incentivize miners to follow segwit’s rules after segwit activates."

This is very vague. How do I know what release is compatible with the segwit fork? "Another segwit-compatible implementation", what does that mean? Sorry, it's not clear to me that this means that 0.14.1 is "another segwit-compatible implementation."

Nowhere on this page does it say to upgrade to 0.13.1 **or later**.

OK, it says "or later" in this paragraph with heading "Not Upgrading", but in a very confusing context:

"For this reason, after segwit reaches locked-in, it is recommended that you either upgrade your full node to Bitcoin Core 0.13.1 or later (or a compatible full node), or that you follow the “not upgrading” instructions in the Full Node section below to use Bitcoin Core 0.13.1 or later as a filter for your pre-segwit software."

I have no idea what this means, especially "a filter for your pre-segwit software."

So does having any version above 0.13.1 of Bitcoin Core (in particular 0.14.1) mean I have segwit and that I'll be on the new soft fork?

If I do have to "upgrade" to the earlier 0.13.1, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means 0.13.1 or later. All versions of Bitcoin Core since enforce the SegWit rules. The upgrade guide was written when only 0.13.1 was available, but since then 0.13.2, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, and 0.14.2 were released. Version 0.15.0 will be released soon.

I've filed an issue to get the page clarified: https://github.com/bitcoin-core/bitcoincore.org/issues/411

Comment: Thanks for filing the issue, I assumed as much but assumptions don't work for me.